# How can I disconnect all my devices from Google Hangout at once?

Tags: google-hangouts

I would like to disconnect all my devices such as computers, phones and tablets from Google Hangout at once. Is there any way to do so?

Comment: Google Talk is dead.

Comment: @ale Good. This solves half of the issue :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way to close of all opened sessions of a Google account is to change the password (see [Keeping your account secure](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/46526?hl=en)) . If the user authorized web sites and applications to access his account, could be necessary to revoke the permissions for them (see [Account Permissions](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3466521?hl=en)).